# Intellij-Idea turn on many watchers on 1 click

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have got about 6 file watchers (for js files, less, tests etc) and sometimes when I run some gulp task (yep, there is gulp and filewatchers, but it's really needed) I must turn off filewatchers. But since I have about 6 filwatchers it's quite not comfortable when I must click one by one each six to turn off. Is it possible to deactive all filewatcher by one clik / macro / any key shourtcut ?

Comment: Try `Ctrl-A` to select all and `Space` to toggle

Comment: nope, impossible to select all this way